# Laravel :method is defined in controller yet it says method not found

Tags: php, laravel-5

I am using laravel 5.2 and following is my code

I am getting error

> ReflectionException in Route.php line 280:
>   Method App\Http\Controllers\Signup_controllers::guestcheckout() does not exist

whats wrong i am doing? plz help

this is my route.php

```
Route::group(array('prefix' => 'signup'), function()
{
    Route::resource('/register', 'Signup_controllers@register');
    Route::resource('/guestcheckout', 'Signup_controllers@guestcheckout');
    Route::resource('/login', 'Signup_controllers@login');
    Route::resource('/logout', 'Signup_controllers@logout');
    Route::resource('/ajaxCheckCustomerEmailExist', 'Signup_controllers@ajaxCheckCustomerEmailExist');
});
```

this is my signup controller

```
    <?php

    namespace App\Http\Controllers;
    use Illuminate\Http\Request;
    use App\Http\Requests;
    use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;
    use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile;
    use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Session1;
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redirect;
    use Image;
    use Session;
    use DB;
    use Mail;

    use App\Http\Models\Frm_mailing_list;
    use App\Http\Models\Frm_contactus;
    use App\Http\Models\Emailautoresponse;
    use App\Http\Models\Adminemail;
    use App\Http\Models\Emailsetting;
    use App\Http\Models\Product_price;

    class Signup_controllers extends Controller
    {
        public function index(Request $request)
        {

        }
        public function register(Request $request)
        {
            include(public_path().'/app/Http/Controllers/action/register_controllers.php'); 
        }
        public function login(Request $request)
        {
            include(public_path().'/app/Http/Controllers/action/login_controllers.php');    
        }
        public function logout()
        {
            Session::flush();
            return Redirect::away(url('/login-registration'))->send();
        }
        public function guestcheckout(Request  $request)
        {
            include(public_path().'/app/Http/Controllers/action/guestcheckout_controllers.php');    
        }

        public function ajaxCheckCustomerEmailExist(Request $request)    
        {
            //Checked By Ranjit
            $email=$request->email;
            $customerData=array('email'=>$email);
            $Customer=new Customer;

            $resultCustomer=$Customer->getByAttributesQuery($customerData);
            if($resultCustomer['recordCount']>0){
                echo "false";
            }else{
                echo "true";
            }
        }
    }
```

when i try to call guestcheckout it says method not found even i have defined it

Answer (score 2):

```
Route::get('/register', 'Signup_controllers@register');
```

You're including controllers within Controllers and alsorts of things are wrong with your code that are going to cause you problems

I'd consider reading the documentation to understand how Laravel works

Answer (score 0):

You are using Resource Controllers incorrectly. See Laravel Documention.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/controllers#resource-controllers

Comment: 1) This is a comment. 2) What makes you think that controller is used incorrectly?

Comment: Resource Controllers can only assign a controller, not a method inside the controller
`Route::resource('photos', 'PhotoController');`

Answer (score 0):

change:

```
Route::resource('/guestcheckout', 'Signup_controllers@guestcheckout');
```

to

```
Route::post('/guestcheckout', 'Signup_controllers@guestcheckout');
```

and do the same thing for other routes, replace `resource` with `post` or `get` for your needs

> Laravel resource routing assigns the typical "CRUD" routes to a
>   controller with a single line of code. and you call it like this : 
>   `Route::resource('photos', 'PhotoController');`